# Laravel 8 - sweet alert is working but ajax not working

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm beginner in Ajax. I'm trying to delete record that from database with sweet alert2. My swal is working but ajax not working. I don't know where is the problem. How can I solve this?

**My blade is:**

```
<p class="card-text"><span class="icon_trash"  type="button" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}" data-target="#default{{ $comment->id }}"></span></p>
```

**My script is:**

```
$(".icon_trash").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
  
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {

                $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('deleteComments',"+id+") }}",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                            id: id
                        },
                        
                        success: function (){
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Deleted!',
                                'Your file has been deleted.',
                                'success'
                                )},
                            error: function(){
                                alert('error');
                            },
                        })
        }
    })
});
```

**My route is:**

```
Route::post('/icerik/comments/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'deleteComments'])->name('deleteComments');
```

**My controller is:**

```
public function deleteComments($id){
        $deletedata= Comment::findOrFail($id);
        $deletedata->delete();


        if($deletedata){
            return response()->json(['status'=>'testss']);
        }else{
            return back();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inject id from frontend to backend during blade compilation in laravel. You need to pass the ID before the view file compiles and is sent to the browser like below:

```
 url: "{{ route('deleteComments',['id' => $comment->id]) }}",
```